# Not adding any classes in compc SWC

Tags: apache-flex, ant, flex4, compc

I'm trying to compile a AIR library project to SWC using compc and it's not including any of my libraries files. Here is my ANT task:

```
<!-- Compile the FCLibrary swc --> 
<target name="compileFCLibrary" > 
 <compc output="${FC_DEPLOY_DIR}" directory="true" locale="en_US" >

    <!-- FCLibrary has Air classes and requires air-config to be loaded -->
    <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/air-config.xml" /> 
    <source-path path-element="${FCLIB_SRC}"/>
    <include-sources dir="${BASE_DIR}/FClibrary/src" includes="*" />
 </compc>
</target>
```

It looks like it includes some files. The directory it creates is as such:

```
/catalog.xml
/library.swf
/local
   /en_US
      /... (*.properties)
/spark
   /components
      /... (*.png)
```

Actually, I don't know if the classes are not including my files. The catalog.xml mentions them.

The error I'm getting on the project that is compiling based on this is:

Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:

Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: LoadFile.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The problem was two fold.

1. The name of the library referenced in ANT was miscased. It was referenced FClibrary.swc when the actual file was FCLibrary.swc
2. mxmlc was not including the library and was failing silently (should have thrown an error).

Didn't work:

```
<include-libraries file="FClibrary.swc" />
```

Worked:

```
<include-libraries file="FCLibrary.swc" />
```